# Does Scikit Learn SelectKBest group continous data itself?

Tags: feature-selection

I want to use the SelectKBest Scikit Learn algorithm (with chi-square test) to reduce the number of features in my ML setup. Unfortunately my feature-data is continous. So my question is, if scikit groups this data itself or is this my job? On the one hand in most cases the input data is continous and chi-sqaure-test seems to be an often used method. On the other hand there is no possibility to define a number of groups.

Thanks
Prickles

Comment: Could you share more details of your setup? Why do you think continuous features would be a problem? And exactly do you mean by groups?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So in my case I got around 200 features of continous data to solve a 2-class problem. Now I want to reduce  the number of features. More precisely I want to use a chi-squared test to check dependencies between every single feature and my output classes. Refering to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Other_chi-squared_tests this only works, if my features are structured in groups/classes.

Comment: I do not see groups. It says that you need to provide n data samples each described by m features. You are right it requires the feature data are either boolean or count frequencies. If features are continuous, it seems you cannot use this method directly. You could try to convert continuous data to boolean for instance by setting a threshold (an average? median? something else? maybe an average of per-class averages?) and having 1 for values > threshold, and 0 for <= threshold. Otherwise, you probably wish to use another method for decreasing the number of features such as PCA or some other.

Comment: Ok, it was probably a little bit unclear, what I meant with groups. In your boolean-threshold-scenario you got two "groups" (1 and 0). So for my data I would set up groups like group1: 0 to threshold_1; group 2: threshold_1 to threshold_2; ...
With those "groups" scikit can make a frequency table. My question was, if scikit maybe recognizes, that the provided data is continous and set up groups by itself. If I understand your comment right, scikit does not do this for me and I have to do it on my own (which sounds logic).
Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thank you for your patient communication, I have learned something too. In your last comment, I am not sure what you mean by a frequency table, or how it would be used in this case.

Comment: Always nice to help each other :D
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Other_chi-squared_tests under section "Example chi-squared test for categorical data" there is an example for what I meant with frequency table. With this table you/keras can calculate the test statistic. Finally keras selects the k features with the highest test statistic.
But do you (or anybody else) know, if keras sets up those groups/classes/whatever by itself?

Comment: I was referring to the sentence: "which must contain only non-negative features such as booleans or frequencies", in the first link you added above, where the word frequencies, I think, is used in a differrent meaning than the word frequency in the term 'frequency table' you used.

Comment: Well, I think, the meaning of frequency is the same in both cases. It says, how often an event happens or two events occur at the same time.
To come back to my original question, does anybody know, if keras groups continous data itself in the case of chi-square SelctKBest?

Comment: Are you sure? When you said: "With those "groups" scikit can make a frequency table", I understood it so that you take all the samples, and count frequencies of your three intervals, i.e. getting only summary frequency data for the whole table. But that is not the same as having some "count" as one of the features, in each sample case a different number. That is, instead of a boolean feature like "a sentence contains a word 'can'", you could also have a numeric feature, like "the number of occurrences of word 'can' in the sentence". But maybe I do not see it right. :)